# Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror, nested-function, return

I just wanted to understand whats happening with this code, and I searched deep into the subject of nested functions and higher order, plus the return statement. But still I wanted to put an end to this doubt(unsure about two return statements in a row) which led me here and help is needed for my understanding, as well to all that apply.

```
function higher_order(){
  return function addNum()
  {  
    return 1+1;
    return function subNum()
    {
      return 1-1;
    };
  };
}; 
alert(higher_order()()());
```

Comment: Whenever you see two returns like that, think about it more carefully, if the function returns 1+1, how is it supposed to also return a function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Try this way:

```
function higher_order(){
    return function addNum(){
        return function subNum(){
            return 1-1;
        };
    };
};
```

higher_order() // returns the function addNum

higher_order()() // returns the function subNum

higher_order()()() // returns the value returned from subNum (0)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the function stops running after the first return statement; your `higher_order` returns the function `addNum`, which returns the number 2; this is not callable, and the exception occurs at the 3rd parentheses `()`

- `higher_order()` returns function `addNum()`
- `addNum()` returns number 2
- `2` (`higher_order()()`) is not callable as a function, thus you get an exception.

You might try `alert(higher_order()())` to see what is the value used for the third call.